# Patch SUPEE-6788 - Error after applying this patch to 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-6788

Most of the site works fine after applying this patch. One exception is that when going to admin->system->cache management->refresh cache, I got the following error. It was just an one-time error. I refreshed the cache again and no error shown. I have no idea what this error means. Should I have any concern?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:745:"Error in file: "/home/frcb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'permission_variable' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `permission_variable` (
  `variable_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Variable ID' ,
  `variable_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '' COMMENT 'Config Path' ,
  `is_allowed` bool NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Mark that config can be processed by filters' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`variable_id`, `variable_name`),
  UNIQUE `UNQ_PERMISSION_VARIABLE_VARIABLE_NAME` (`variable_name`)
) COMMENT='System variables that can be processed via content filter' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci";i:1;s:954:"#0 /home/frcb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/frcb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.1.1', '1.6.1.2')
#2 /home/frcb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.1.1', '1.6.1.2')
#3 /home/frcb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home/frcb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/frcb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/frcb/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/frcb/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:23:"/index.php/admin/cache/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 5):

This means patch's 'admin_setup' update script was executed before and somehow it was overwritten at core_resource table, so Magento trying to run it again but getting exception, thrown initially by Mysql as tables that this upgrade script trying to create is already there.

I'd follow below steps to fix it:

- Check `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php` and figure out what are new tables and data being added/updated.
- Backup your current database to be safe
- Cross check with database if all table, data already present.
- If yes, update core_resource table for code : `admin_setup`, set `version` and `data_version` to `1.6.1.2` , clear cache and you are done
- If database table/data not matching with upgrade script, this means upgrade was not finished properly when last executed, to fix it, Delete table that was created by partial upgrade,e.g for your case `permission_variable` and clear cache to run upgrade script again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I checked the new tables. Tables and data are there and correct. version and data_version are already 1.6.1.2. Like I said, the error only showed once. So maybe the script worked fine the second time?

Comment: Ah! I missed  "I refreshed the cache again and no error shown"  yeah looks like script worked fine. core_resource  entry was cached I guess.

Comment: What can happen when you apply the patch with Magento cache fully enabled and compiler on. Disable cache and compiler before applying patches, installing modules. Saves a world of hurt.

Comment: It's also possible that someone else hit the site at the same time as you. Magento, in its infinite wisdom, will run all applicable upgrade scripts on every request, even if the same scripts are already running in another request.

Comment: @Agop - running upgrade script on production env without maintenance flag turned on is terrible idea.

Comment: @anshuman Yup. Either way, Magento's upgrade scripts are terribly designed. They should never run *per request*, period. There should be a manual trigger for them (via the CLI, for example).

Comment: Yeah, I ran the patch on production without maintenance flag turned on, and the cache wasn't disabled. Will be more careful in the future. At this moment, should I still have any concern, although everything seems fine?

Comment: @agop - Also disable the crontab call to `cron.sh/cron.php`, I've had a cron run totally bollox things up. There are places where Magento just totally rules in the wheel reinvention world. Reinventing new ways of messing up module installs that are strangely related to the old ways of messing up, rounding like it was 1988, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll do that. My question now is: the error showed up once, but no more afterwards. The site seems running fine. Should I have any concern that something might be broken due to this one-time error?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue while patching a Magento 1.7 site in a sandbox environment.

The patch would be applied correctly and everything would work until I cleared the cache. After  clearing the cache, Magento would keep trying to run the 1.6.1.2 admin_setup upgrade and clearing the cache again wouldn't fix the problem.

After some investigation, I figured that Magento incremented the `admin_setup` resource's version in the cache, but not in the actual database.

I ended up fixing it by manually updating the `core_resource` table.

`` UPDATE `core_resource` 
SET 
    `version` = '1.6.1.2',
    `data_version` = '1.6.1.2'
WHERE
    `code` = 'admin_setup'; ``

Comment: Just a little complement of information. I think the underlying issue is triggered by not disabling the cache before applying the patch. I'm not 100% sure thought.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after clearing cache. `admin_setup` versions in table `core_resource` where ok.

Solution was simply to login to admin again.